# Applications of quantum computing for science popularization

Tags: applications

I need to do some popularization of science for an event, and I would like to talk about the "best" applications of quantum computing.

I know there is code-breaking (Shor algorithm), simulation of quantum systems, deep learning, etc.

However, I would like an example that talks to the public. I think I have read at some point that we could be using chemistry simulation simulating drugs on computers. So basically the concept of drugs would enter in the simulation era.

However, as I haven't found source easily on this again I would like to check if it is science fiction or it is true we could do it by simulating large molecules (because if it is true it would be for my perspective the best application of quantum computer by far).

I am also interested in other nice applications of quantum computing "not too abstract" if you have ideas or sources on them.

Comment: I would urge you not say that deep learning is one of the best applications of quantum computing to a general audience, or to any audience for that matter. It will take a lot more work from the field to reinforce a claim like that.

Answer (score 4):

There is good reason to believe that quantum computers will eventually play an important role in drug discovery.  Perhaps the best way to show that it's not science fiction is to talk about the startups forming that are focused on QC-enabled drug discovery.  The companies that I know of that fit this description are

- [ProteinQure](https://www.proteinqure.com/)
- [HQS](https://quantumsimulations.de/)
- [GTN](https://gtn.ai/)
- [Qulab](https://qulab.com/)
- [Riverlane](https://riverlane.io/)