# What Are The Most Promising Real-World Applications For Quantum Machine Learning

Tags: quantum-algorithms, simulation, hamiltonian-simulation, machine-learning, applications

I know this has been asked before in different ways, however, I am interested in something with a degree of clarity and focus not found in other questions.

---

What I am looking to get is a list of the most promising and impactful applications that Quantum Machine Learning and resources and references that I can use to understand more.

As a prerequisite I would ask that the 'application' have a **real-world use case** and **associated industry**.

> i.e. If we are saying that Quantum Machine Learning gives us Quadratic speedups for Unstructured Search Algorithms than it would be prudent to specify that this could accelerate Drug Discovery and/or Materials Development (and then link to things about Grover's Search Algorithm, Unstructured Search Algorithms, etc.).

**Thanks in advance for your help!**

---

***NOTE:* I have reviewed the following StackExchange links prior to asking this:**

- [Applications of quantum computing for science popularization](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8417/applications-of-quantum-computing-for-science-popularization)
- [Do we really know how a universal quantum computer can be used to revolutionize the design of new drugs or materials?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4150/do-we-really-know-how-a-universal-quantum-computer-can-be-used-to-revolutionize)
- [Are there any examples of anyone applying quantum algorithms to problems in computational biology?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4169/are-there-any-examples-of-anyone-applying-quantum-algorithms-to-problems-in-comp)
- [Example of Hamiltonian Simulation solving interesting problem?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4107/example-of-hamiltonian-simulation-solving-interesting-problem)

**...and the links on this page were used for background info in addition to an Engineering, Machine Learning and Data Science background (and the TF Whitepaper).**

- [Introductory material for quantum machine learning](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2151/introductory-material-for-quantum-machine-learning)

Comment: the answers for quantum computing and QML are likely to be quite different, I would suggest to specialise the question on one of the two. Anyway, imo this question is very hard to answer properly for a number of reasons. For QML in particular, because I don't think there is widespread consensus as to what the "most promising real-world applications" are. Things get even worse when you throw "industry applications" into the mix, as you'll find plenty of arguably debatable claims around.

Comment: That said, any review on the topic will give you a plethora of possible applications and references. The majority of papers on these topic will also include lists of possible applications in their introductions. A rencent one on QML with *plenty* of references is https://quantum-journal.org/views/qv-2020-03-17-32/. IMO a more sensible approach would be to start from these and then ask here more focused questions about things you'll find unclear in these papers

Comment: another related question here about QC in particular is https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2603/55

Comment: Edited the question to specifically reference QML. Thanks for the other comments, I will check out the links.